# Show $\gcd(8^n, 4^n +2^n +1)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Show that for all $n\in\mathbb{N},\,\gcd(8^n, 4^n +2^n +1)=1$.
I understand one way is to use Extended Euclidean algorithm but the process seems infinitely long. How may I use any easy method to show this identity?

Comment: Well, $\;8^n\;$ is even (at least three times divisible by two), whereas the other factor is very odd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$8^n-(2^n-1)(4^n+2^n+1)=1$ Hence $gcd(8^n,4^n+2^n+1)=1$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** The only prime that divides $8^n$ is $2$. Does $2$ divide $4^n+2^n+1$?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that:

- $8^n=2^{3n}$
- $4^n+2^n+1=$ even $+$ even $+$ odd $=$ odd

In other words:

- $2$ is the only prime factor of $8^n$
- $2$ is not a prime factor of $4^n+2^n+1$

Therefore $\gcd(8^n,4^n+2^n+1)=1$.